# Background Agent timer

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app which is using a background agent.
I know that the agent executes every 30 minutes.
I'm only want to execute some code once a day maybe at 00:00:01
How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Periodic tasks / background agents do NOT execute every 30 minutes.  They execute at varying times, and those times are dependent upon several factors.  They cannot be counted upon to execute at any given interval, and the smallest amount of time that you should consider that it *should* excecute is about every hour.  It can execute more frequently than that, but you should not count on this.

One of the things that the phone takes into account when performing periodic tasks is the timing of when the phone powers up the radios, because starting up the radios takes quite a bit of power, compared to when the phone is idle.

Also, you should consider that some users will disable periodic tasks.  Because of that, and the above notes about periodic tasks, you should write your program in such a way that it is possible that the periodic task will never execute, and account for that within the app when it executes.  But you should especially not expect that ANY periodic task will execute at one second past midnight, as there is no way to set a time for something to execute.

Perhaps this will be possible in WP8, but it is not possible in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

I guess periodic tasks will help you in that case. You may find other details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask(v=vs.92).aspx